# mysql update with table abbreviations

Tags: php, mysql

Some time ago I wrot a PHP script and defined some MySQL table names as constants. Now I am adding some updates and in order to simplify the readability I wanted to use table abreviations in the UPDATE-statements.
In SELECT-Statements I use them without problems like that `SELECT * FROM table t INNER JOIN table2 t2......` but in the UPDATE-Statement it keeps telling me that my column name is not found.

Here an example:

```
$sql = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `" . TBLCUSTMANAGMNT . "` m
                            INNER JOIN `" . TBLCUSTOMERS . "` c ON (c.id = m.customerID)
                            SET `c.name` = :cName, `m.posOrder` = :posOrder, `m.posDeliver` = :posDeliver, `m.transactionFirst` = :transactionFirst, `m.transactionLast` = :transactionLast,
                                `m.transactionCount` = :transactionCount, `m.posCount` = :posCount, `m.posParticipation` = :posParticipation, `m.active` = :active
                            WHERE c.id = :id AND c.guid = :guid");
```

After executing I get an error telling me, that the column c.name is not found.

Do I have to explicitely write the full table name like that: **tableName**.**columnName**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `TBLCUSTMANAGMNT` be `$TBLCUSTMANAGMNT`? How are you assigning it? same with customer table

Comment: nope, because as I said at the beginning these are not variables but constants and constants do not have a "$"

Comment: Have you tried echoing the string out and running it manually?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Was speed reading! I got it - Will leave comment there as someone else might do same thing

Answer (score 1):

When using backticks you need to do

```
`c`.`name`
```

rather than

```
`c.name`
```

Comment: My pleasure squire

Answer (score 0):

You are using quoting in wrong way. `` `c.name` `` - MySQL will look for column 'c.name'. `` `c`.`name` `` - this is right way to get column 'name' from table 'c'.

Comment: For Reference: They are actually called backticks not quotes